# Deep linking Skype for business app with react native mobile app

Tags: react-native, mobile, skypedeveloper

How can I redirect a user to skype for the business app if it is already installed in the device? Do I need to register my app to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native';

Linking.openURL('sip:example@example.com').then();
```

It will open a chat window with user `example@example.com`

**Edit:**
To open app without any section, change the uri like this:

```
Linking.openURL('ms-sfb://start').then().catch(err => { //app not installed });
```

[Docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skype-for-business-uris/sfbmobileuri)

Comment: Thanks Mahdi but is it possible to not open any specific section but just to launch an app?And we need to perform actions on SKYPE FOR BUSINESS app.Everything is working as expected with SKYPE.

Comment: @Pragati I edited my response, hope that's what you're looking for